# Anki addon development: Error creating an editor button

Tags: python-3.x, anki

I'm trying to add a button in Anki toolbar.

It worked!

But, when I click the button, it show me an error message, it seems an event listener.

What I need to do?
I tried to implement onBridgeCmd, but it doesn't work (I don't know how to implement).

[image]

```py
def blur_text(editor):
    showdialogtitle(editor.currentField, 'anki')

def addBlurButton(buttons,editor):
    editor._links['blur_text'] = blur_text    
    buttons += [editor._addButton(ICON_PATH, "blur","Blur Text")]
    return buttons 

addHook("setupEditorButtons",addBlurButton)
```

Error:

> Debug info: Anki 2.1.35 (4e12c7ef) Python 3.8.5 Qt 5.12.2 PyQt 5.12.1
> Platform: Linux Flags: frz=False ao=True sv=2 Add-ons, last update
> check: 2021-01-21 14:27:50 Add-ons possibly involved: ⁨Anki IPA,
> blur_text, search_in_dictionaries⁩
>
> Caught exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/webview.py",
> line 37, in cmd
> return json.dumps(self.onCmd(str))   File "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/webview.py",
> line 123, in _onCmd
> return self._onBridgeCmd(str)   File "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/webview.py",
> line 547, in _onBridgeCmd
> return self.onBridgeCmd(cmd)   File "", line 2, in onBridgeCmd   File
> "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anki/hooks.py",
> line 638, in decorator_wrapper
> return repl(*args, **kwargs)   File "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anki/hooks.py",
> line 635, in repl
> return new(_old=old, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/element/snap/anki-woodrow/27/.local/share/Anki2/addons21/search_in_dictionaries/**init**.py",
> line 230, in on_bridge_cmd
> _old(editor, command)   File "", line 2, in onBridgeCmd   File
> "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anki/hooks.py",
> line 638, in decorator_wrapper
> return repl(*args, **kwargs)   File "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anki/hooks.py",
> line 635, in repl
> return new(_old=old, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/element/snap/anki-woodrow/27/.local/share/Anki2/addons21/blur_text/**init**.py",
> line 59, in on_bridge_cmd
> _old(editor, command)   File "", line 2, in onBridgeCmd   File
> "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anki/hooks.py",
> line 638, in decorator_wrapper
> return repl(*args, **kwargs)   File "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anki/hooks.py",
> line 635, in repl
> return new(_old=old, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/element/snap/anki-woodrow/27/.local/share/Anki2/addons21/799647424/main.py",
> line 183, in on_bridge_cmd
> _old(editor, command)   File "/snap/anki-woodrow/27/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/editor.py",
> line 385, in onBridgeCmd
> (type, ord, nid, txt) = cmd.split(":", 3) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the button's event name, I needed to change it, for some reason, "blur_text", is used in the Anki system.

```
def contrast_text(editor: Editor) -> None:
    ...

def add_contrast_button(buttons: List[str], editor: Editor) -> List[str]:
    button = editor.addButton(ICON_PATH, "contrast", contrast_text)
    buttons.append(button)
    return buttons

addHook("setupEditorButtons", add_contrast_button)
```